# IE11 issue with absolutely positioned flexbox takes up width of parent instead of contents

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

Simple repro:

```html
    <div style="display: inline-block; position: relative; border: 1px solid black;">
        short
        <div style="display: flex; position: absolute; border: 1px solid black; top: 100%; left: 0;;">longerbox</div>
    </div>
```

The flexbox element (longerbox) does not take up the width of its content like it does on Chrome. Is there a fix for this?

[image]

Comment: Have you considered moving the `position: relative` one level up? https://jsfiddle.net/t1aLzbyq/1/

Comment: You haven't defined enough properties on the inner `div` to give it a width. Set both `left` and `right` or an explicit `width` property. Elements that have `position: absolute` have different sizing rules compared to normal block-level elements.

Comment: @Michael_B can't do that. this snippet is an item in a menu with many more items.

Comment: @Dai position: absolute should take the width of its content in normal circumstances, considering it works in Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

Ok figured it out. Need an extra container for the flexbox just for positioning. i.e. don't have position: absolute and flexbox on the same element.

```html
<div style="display: inline-block; position: relative; border: 1px solid black">
    short
    <div style="position: absolute; border: 1px solid black; top: 100%; left: 0">
        <div style="display: flex">longerbox</div>
    </div>
</div>
```